# What are the things I should do after getting into Germany?

Tags: germany, resident-permit, eu, blue-card, foreign-employment

[image]
I recently got the type D Visa for the employment purpose. Now I'm confused. What are the things I shall be doing after entering Germany. When I checked my visa I could see the above lines being printed. Can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 2):

You have been issued a D-Visa for

- Blue Card **§9a AufenthG**
- with permission, as a foreigner, to work **§39 AufenthG**
- with a specialized qualification **§2 BeschV**

---

The following steps are needed before you start working

- Accommodation and Registration
- Registration at the Foreigners Office
- Becoming am member of a Health insurance company  (Krankenkasse)
- Registration for Television / Radio Tax  (Rundfunksbeitrag)
- Useful documents to have
- Leaving Germany

**Tip**:
Report in to your employer, since they may assist you in going through these steps!

---

**Step 1**: *Accommodation and Registration*

One you have arrived in Germany, the first thing you have to do is find an accommodation.

Once you have a contract for an accommodation, you must register (**Anmeldung**) your residence

- this must be done within 14 days **after** moving in

Depending on which city your in, the office may have different names

- City Hall, **Bürgeramt**, **Meldebehörde**

  - appointments are often needed

Togeather with your rental contract you should also recieve a

- **Einzugsbestätigung des Wohnungsgebers (Vermieter)**

which is a confirmation from the landlord needed for registration.

The result will be a **Meldeschein**, which is proof of registration and will be needed later.

**Tax Card / Number** (Lohnsteuerkarte)
Can (must) also be applied for if you don't have one.

The Tax card is now electronic and has the wonderful name of:

- **[ElektronischeLohnSteuerAbzugsMerkmale (ELStAM)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elektronische_Lohnsteuerabzugsmerkmale)**

They will ask you which church you belong to and if it belongs to the **church tax system** an extra tax is deducted.

'Church of England' is one that **does not** belong to the **church tax system**  and of course **none** is also a valid answer

- in such cases no Church tax will be deducted

This Tax information should be given to your employer.

---

**Step 2**: *Registration at the Foreigners Office* (Ausländerbehörde)

- *Step 2* **does not apply** to EU Citizens

**Precondition**: **Meldeschein**, Passport and possibly working contact

Since you have been issued a D-Visa, this must now be replaced with a

- residence permit (**Aufenthaltstitel**)

  - which in your case will be a **Blue Card**

Since the issuing of the residence card may take some time a

- a temporary residence permit (**Fiktionsbescheinigung**)

may be issued, which serves as a replacement until the final **Aufenthaltstitel** is issued.

**Note**:
The **Ausländerbehörde** will know who you are and what you want, since they are the ones who granted the visa.

---

**Step 3**: *Becoming am member of a Health insurance company* (Krankenkasse)

See this answer on how to become a [member of a Krankenkasse (Health insurance provider)](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/19246/17166)

- which is the compulsory health insurance (Gesetzliche Krankenversicherung)

This information will also be needed by your employer.

---

**Step 4**: *Registration for Television / Radio Tax*  (Rundfunksbeitrag)

See this answer which contains some [background information about this topic](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/6401/17166)

The registration process can be done one here:

- [Der Rundfunkbeitrag - Wohnung anmelden](https://www.rundfunkbeitrag.de/buergerinnen_und_buerger/formulare/anmelden/index_ger.html)

See this answer which contains some [information what to do when moving or leaving Germany](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/12549/ard-zdf-deregistration-before-leaving-germany/17323#17323)

---

**Useful documents to have**

For a **long time residency**, some documents may be needed that is easier to get

- while you are still in your home country

This answer [lists these documents and for what they may be needed for](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/18075/17166) in the future.

---

**Leaving Germany**

- de-register your residence and Rundfunkbeitrag

While working in Germany you will paying in to the pension system

- [How to apply for a Versicherungsverlauf](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/19380/17166)

describes how to get the needed document which proofs your payments and may be useful when appling for a pension later on in life.

Comment: When I started working for a German firm in October 2015, it was my employer that asked me for my church and registered me with the tax office, and registered me with the Krankenkasse (after I had started work).  Note that I was (am) an EU citizen, which may make a difference.

Comment: @MartinBonner accourding to the wiki artical, that is also possible. For Berlin it is listed as something that can be done during registration. So it wozld seem that there are multiple ways. With the Krankenkasse, one should try to inform oneself which is the best offer **beforehand**, since changing is not so simple. Citizenship does not play a role here.

Comment: Does this mean I have already  been granted blue card or do I need to apply for it once I arrive in Germany  ?

Comment: @ShivaGautam Yes, everything has been granted. It only needs to be issued after arrival.

Comment: I didn't read everything, but a little detail: you do not need all of this before starting to work, only before you can get the first pay check.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Looks like I am in a big trouble again. I couldn't book an appointment for applying Blue Card because of no permanent accommodation. My visa expires next week and with the new salary threshold for 2020 am I still going to get the Blue Card ?

Comment: @ShivaGautam When did you arrive in Germany and are you now working? What type of place are you living? Is your salary less than €55,200? This should be asked as an extra question with reference to this answer.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I arrived in November and I am working currently. I am in Munich. I have an IT Job with annual income of 42k per year. I qualified for Blue Card last year so the embassy granted me the Blue Card Visa but since I couldn't apply for blue card last year. Will I still be eligible for it ? I am the same guy that asked this question .

Comment: @ShivaGautam You haven't answered the question about what type place your are staying at the moment, which is the cause of not gerring the appointment.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I am staying at my friend's which makes my mailing address c/o. I have been trying to get the appointment since a month but could not get one. As you have told above that blue card has been granted . It only needs to be issued after arrival. Am I still eligible for it in 2020 because my salary is less than the new criteria ?

Comment: @ShivaGautam You have a visa, but not the Blue Card residence permit. You are in violation of the residence laws and the Ausländerbehörde is probably wondering where you are. To resolve you must get a **Untermieter** contract from your friends and register. I am surprised the your employer allows this. For 2019 € 53.600, so with € 42.000 I am surprised you got the BlueCard visa at all. For all new applications, renewals or pending applications the 2020 sum of €55,200 is required. You should consider talking to your employer to resolve this mess, which also envoles them.

Comment: @ShivaGautam When does you visa expire? And just to be clear, if you **have** registered at your friends place, that is your permanent residence. And if you did, when?

Comment: @MarkJohnson 55,200 Euro is only the generic Blue Card salary border. Besides this, the salary border for Blue Card for shortage occupation (which includes IT) is 43,056 Euro per year (2020).

Answer (score 1):

In such cases, one only needs to do the following steps **actively on him/herself** after entering Germany (for others he/she will be asked and/or get post):

1. Rent an apartment and register there --> this is needed for steps 2 and 3
2. Get a health insurance (if one is working and his/her salary is lower than 62,550 Euro per year, he/she should be registered at public insurance, but nobody prohibits him/her from taking a private one on top of that later)
3. Apply for a Blue Card or other residence permit at the Ausländerbehörde before your visa expires

That's it!

Comment: Points 1 and 2 are covered in the answer from Mark Johnson.  Point 3 doesn't apply to the OP - they *already* have the Blue Card.

Comment: Point 1 is indeed covered. However, point 2 (health insurance) by Mark Johnson provides a wrong information: "which is the compulsory health insurance (Gesetzliche Krankenversicherung)", cause I can expect some Blue Card holders also being eligible for private insurance. 

Other points in the answer from Mark Johnson are not really mandatory and are therefore misleading.

Finally, the question claims that they DO NOT have a Blue Card: "I recently got the type D Visa for the employment purpose." Please see https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/12097/13223 for details.