# Accommodation Proof, Germany Work Visa

Tags: working-visas, germany, accommodation

I need to show accommodation proof for Germany Work Visa. I was told by someone that booking.com can help to book without paying any prepayment and if your dates change, you can cancel too without paying any extra money.

Now when I'm going to booking.com it says that maximum I can book for 30 days.

How can I book for 6 months in advance?

Comment: Did it work for you doing the separate bookings? We’re about to go through the same process. There is conflicting information everywhere!

Comment: @Emily National visas for Germany are granted by the local Immigration authority in Germany. The embassy is asking for the **intended place of stay in Germany** so that they know were to send the application for approval. Booking an accommodation is a **compleate waste of time** and not required for a National visa  application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Mark is right that as per guidelines you are not required to present accommodation proof in the embassy. Still, we don't want to take chances. So what I did. I did Six bookings from booking.com, for one month each. For example:

1. First booking from June 1 - June 30th
2. Second booking from July 1st - July 31st and so on ...

If I wanted I could have canceled because there were no cancelation charges, still I stayed in for the first month and when I got my permanent stay I moved there.

I hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the registration of your residence, which is not the booking of a hotel, but the renting of an apartment after moving in.

Read **Step 1** of the link below

- the issued **Meldeschein** is the proof that you need to show the **Ausländerbehörde**

---

**Sources**:

- [resident permit - What are the things I should do after getting into Germany?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/19397/17166)

Comment: your answer solved the biggest problem, WOW!! Provides a checklist and step by step procedure. Could you please also tell me when I am in India, how can I book 6 months accommodation in advance?

Comment: @paul You basicly can't. For an D-Visa Application you don't need a rent contract. So I think that there is a misunderstanding here. Getting a rent contract is what you do **after** arrival (you after all want to see what you will rent). Rent a room in a Pension / Hotel for the first week and then start looking.

Comment: can you share source of this fact? I don't want to be blank if the officer asks where you're going to stay. Officer has valid question though.

Comment: @paul The D-Visa Application form asks: **Intended place of stay in Germany, Street,  number (if known)**. Since you don't have a rented flat (as 99% don't when applying) you leave it blank.