# What is the process to get EU blue card once I am in Germany on Employment Visa?

Tags: working-visas, germany, blue-card

Background :

I have German national Visa (Employment) approved for 3 months.
I had submitted few additional documents required for Blue card applicants during Visa application at German Consulate, Mumbai. Such as ANABIN docs along with degree certificate.

I have a job contract for indefinite period.

Questions :

1.What is the process to get Blue card once I reach Germany ?
2. Which documents are required during above process ?
3. Will I need apostille on degree certificate even if I have ANABIN docs ?
4. In my case what will be the validity duration of Blue Card ?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, there should be no specific process, you can just enter Germany on your current visa and apply for a Blue Card at the Ausländerbehörde, if you satisfy the Blue Card requirements. See https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/19565/13223 for more details. The requirements for Blue Card you can find in Google.

Comment: My employer is moving me to Germany on the "Work and Residence Permit" for specialists visa. Can I follow the same procedure listed above to convert it to the EU Blue Card? - Vish

Answer (score 2):

As I have received Blue Card finally I am updating the answer for anyone interested:

Once you reach Germany on German national Visa, do the following (based on my experience)

1. Get a flat/residence. make a rental agreement.
2. Go to the City office and register to get 'Anmeldung'.
3. Get health insurance and obtain a certificate for the same.
4. Obtain an appointment from your local foreign office for blue card interview.
5. Fill the blue card application form. Carry - Degree certificate,
   Anmeldung, Rental agreement, proof of sufficient living space, a
   photo, passport, 100Euro (may vary), etc.
6. Officer will verify your documents.
7. Officer will ask you to pay the fee.
8. Officer will issue a temporary residence permit printed on paper.
9. In about 6 weeks blue card will arrive at your home on post!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to convert your visa to a blue card then the basic requirements still need to be met, such as salary, qualifications etc. even if you are already in Germany.

You should go along to your local ABH (Ausländerbehörde) and talk to them about doing this.  They will then advise you what exactly they wish to see for your specific circumstances and if this is possible or not.

If you already got your degree/qualifications verified via ANABIN then it should be possible to just resubmit this information again during the application.

The duration of the Blue card will be valid for 4 years from the date of issue, or for the duration of your contract + 3 months (if you have a limited contract).